# Are the words "negative", "nego" and "niger", "nox" cognates?

Tags: etymology

Are the Latin words "[negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_(photography))", "nego" and "niger", "nox" are cognates?
In accordance to bible, word is a light and its absence is a dark.

Answer (score 4):

A few things first:

- "Negative" comes from *negō*; the photography meaning came millennia later and isn't really relevant to the etymology
- *Negō* comes from the negater *nē* plus the old word for "to speak", which looked something like **agjō*—so *nē* is what's relevant here

Now, for the three words in question:

- *Nē* goes all the way back to PIE without change; it's also the source of English negatives like "un-", "not", "no," and "never" (which accumulated other morphemes through Jespersen's Cycle)
- *Nox* comes from PIE `*nokʷts`, which *might* come from `*n-gʷ-` "naked"
- *Niger*'s etymology is uncertain, but it might come from `*nokʷts` "night"

So, it's possible that *nox* and *niger* are related, but it's not completely accepted. It's pretty clear that *nē* isn't related within the timeframe that we can reconstruct; anything before that is pure speculation.

---

P.S. In linguistics (and most other sciences), the Bible isn't generally considered a reliable source. While you may believe in it, many other people in the world do not, and it can't be backed up with evidence.